# Expected: end of statement error -- Coding a Volatile Formula

Tags: excel, vba, volatile, excel-indirect

I have two volatile formulas that work fine when it is hard coded in Excel.. but this formula will be dynamic so I am inserting it in VBA and will loop later on.

```
    Worksheets("Interest Calculator").Range("E5").Formula = "=IF($C5>Inputs!E8-1,"",IF($C5<=Portfolio_Duration,(SUM($E$4:E4)+$G4)/Portfolio_Duration,(SUM(INDIRECT("E"&$C5-Portfolio_Duration+4):INDIRECT("E"&$C5+3))+$G4)/Portfolio_Duration))"
```

I am getting a compile error: Expected: end of statement and the "E" in INDIRECT("E"&$C5+3))+$G4)/Portfolio_Duration))" is highlighted.

How can I fix this code? Thanks!

If it helps, Error Duration = 55 AND Portfolio Duration = 36

Comment: Double the double quotes so that "" (two double quotes) would become """" (four double quotes) and "E" would become ""E""

Comment: When you put double `""` in a formula in VBA you have to also surround that with `""`. So change `"=IF($C5>Inputs!E8-1,"",` to `"=IF($C5>Inputs!E8-1,"""",` and see if that works. Also around "E" as sktneer has pointed out :)

Comment: @dwirony - FYI - It's not that `""` has to be surrounded by `""` - it's that each `"` needs to become `""`.  E.g. `""` needs to become `""""` (which might **appear** to just be placing an extra `"` at each end), but `IF(E1="""",` (for example) would need to become `IF(E1="""""""",`, not just `IF(E1="""""",`.

Comment: @YowE3K oooh. Noted. Just one of those things I saw and learned on the spot one day.

Comment: @dwirony - I've found that hanging around SO tends to increase your knowledge by at least one fact a day.  Sure, sometimes those facts are unimportant, but it is still always an upward trend in knowledge. :)  (Now, if I could just find a way to stop forgetting at least **two** facts every day. :( )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double all the `"`

```
   Worksheets("Interest Calculator").Range("E5").Formula = "=IF($C5>Inputs!E8-1,"""",IF($C5<=Portfolio_Duration,(SUM($E$4:E4)+$G4)/Portfolio_Duration,(SUM(INDIRECT(""E""&$C5-Portfolio_Duration+4):INDIRECT(""E""&$C5+3))+$G4)/Portfolio_Duration))"
```

Comment: I want to do a For Loop with

Comment: @Rome876 new question = new post.